# HTML encode into Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, unicode, encoding

I have a code that runs on in HTML/ASPX files.
I have dictionary that maps between ISO Currency Code and their Currency Symbol encoded.
For instance:

```
"EUR", "&#x80;"

"GBP", "&#xA3;"
```

In HTML pages tag <%= converts this code with no problem, but when I try to do that in backend C# code, GBP code converted with no problem with HttpUtility.HtmlDecode but EUR
Does not.
[image]

Even stackoverflow translates EUR code to unknown symbol.
It looks correct to me:
[image]
But don't know how to resolve it now.

How can I translate &#X80(semicolon) to € sign?

Comment: Try using the HTML entity code for euro, &#8364;  ... [.Net Fiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LcZCWR)

Comment: What does this have to do with Excel?

Comment: It works fine when I take "&#x80;" to HTML while using ASPX tag <%=
But now I need to show this symbol in EXCEL report and there I get empty string as far as "&#x80;" converted to "\u0080" for some reason.

Comment: thank you @quaabaam. I will try this approach.

Answer (score 1):

I want to highlight the answer from @quaabaam that helped me to resolve

I replaced

```
"EUR", "&#x80;"
```

to

```
"EUR","&#8364;"
```

Verified it in different areas on the system's code. So far so good.
Thanks, [quaabaam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9541862/quaabaam)